# Conversion error when using to_datetime to convert mixed date formats in large CSV database

Tags: python, pandas, csv, filter, bigdata

I have a big csv database of contracts (25 mln lines and around 7 gb). I need to filter it out expired contracts to reduce the size for further calculations. The array of expiration dates contains dates in mixed formats (dd/mm/yyyy and dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm/ss).

I've tried using this code:

```
#reading database
reader = pd.read_csv(path_contracts, sep="|", header=0, low_memory=False, chunksize=1000000)   
output = "Base_Filtered.csv"
 
#filtering chunks
for contracts in reader:
        contracts[name_date_end] = pd.to_datetime(contracts[name_date_end], dayfirst=True, format='mixed')
        #conditional
        contracts = contracts[(contracts[name_date_end]>=date_report)]  
        #outputing filtered chunks     
        contracts.to_csv(output, sep="|")
```

But I am getting this error:

```
pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 31.08.8020, at position 3584
```

I've checked position 3584 and it returns 06.11.2021:

```
print(contracts.at[3584,name_date_end])
06.11.2021
```

So I tried to make a smaller version of my database (5k lines) that would contain this element and it works perfectly fine.

Before trying filtering chunks of data, I've tried to filter the whole database at once. It yielded same error but on different position.

Couldn't figure out the source and solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you expect only two formats for dates or datetimes, and your data has more than that but you don't know what they might be.

For such a large dataset it'd be difficult to interrogate it beforehand and get everything perfect, so maybe you need to run this process iteratively and interactively:

- any row with a datetime that doesn't match your predefined formats gets kicked out to a separate file
- you could then inspect this "bads" file and figure out what new format you need to add to your main script

I mocked up a really simple input CSV:

```
1,1/1/2001
2,2/2/2002 12/34/56
3,3.3.2003
4,6.1.2001
5,7.1.2001-5:38:19
```

The following script:

- defines a list of expected datetime formats
- opens two files for writing and creates csv.writers around them
- starts reading the input csv:

  - it tries all the predefined datetime formats until it succeeds and returns, or

    - if it doesn't succeed returns None
  - if the previous step didn't succeeded, that row gets written to bads for analysis, else...
  - it filters by the good datetime, logging/printing the filtered-out rows (just for debug, on this really small, sample dataset); it also standardizes the date-times to the ISO format

```py
import csv
from datetime import datetime

fmts = [
    r"%d/%m/%Y",
    r"%d/%m/%Y %H/%M/%S",
]


def parse_dt(s: str) -> datetime | None:
    for fmt in fmts:
        try:
            dt = datetime.strptime(s, fmt)
            return dt
        except ValueError:
            continue

    return None


filtered = csv.writer(
    open("output_filtered.csv", "w", newline=""),
    delimiter=",",
)

bad = csv.writer(
    open("output_bad.csv", "w", newline=""),
    delimiter=",",
)

reader = csv.reader(
    open("input.csv", newline=""),
    delimiter=",",
)

for row in reader:
    dt = parse_dt(row[1])

    if dt is None:
        bad.writerow(row)
        continue

    if dt < datetime(2002, 1, 1):
        row[1] = dt.isoformat()  # standardize on ISO format
        filtered.writerow(row)
    else:
        print(f"dropped {dt}")
```

That yields the following CSVs:

```
output_bad.csv:
3,3.3.2003
4,6.1.2001
5,7.1.2001-5:38:19


output_filtered.csv:
1,2001-01-01T00:00:00
```

and prints the following to stdout:

```
dropped 2002-02-02 12:34:56
```

I'd then take `3.3.2003` and `7.1.2001-5:38:19`, update fmts with `r"%d.%m.%Y` and `r"%d.%m.%Y-%H:%M:%S"`:

```py
fmts = [
    r"%d/%m/%Y",
    r"%d/%m/%Y %H/%M/%S",
    r"%d.%m.%Y",
    r"%d.%m.%Y-%H:%M:%S",
]
```

and rerun:

```
dropped 2002-02-02 12:34:56
dropped 2003-03-03 00:00:00
```

The bads CSV is empty, and the filtered CSV looks like:

```
1,2001-01-01T00:00:00
4,2001-01-06T00:00:00
5,2001-01-07T05:38:19
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me! It did indeed filtered out everything that I’ve needed and there were no bad outputs. So could it be that its pandas or hardware couldn’t handle an array this big?

Comment: @MaliciousBreadBoy, you're welcome. I just noticed a version of my code crept in where the `%d.%m.%Y` format was already present. If you ran that version then indeed nothing would look bad. If you look at your code and see that format, maybe remove it just to prove that indeed your CSV had at least 3 formats (and that Pandas was complaining for good reason). Anyways, cheers!